# Sending data from the Python TCP Socket(as server) to the JS client

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, tcp

So, the question is in the following: How?

I have already implemented the TCP server on Python. It sends the data to a client(also implemented on Python).

So now I want to make it on JavaScript

Any reccomendations or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently cannot connect to a TCP socket from plain JavaScript.

You have to rely on XHR or Websockets.

For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337074/4760822) answer.

**Edit:**

In Python you could use SocketIO to create a WebSocket. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/makaimc/python-websockets-example).

Comment: but in case of using WebSockets- as I understood, I have to rewrite the server to work with the web sockets, not with the TCP?

Comment: Correct, see my edit for a WebSocket example in python.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I also have one more question:
what about XHR? I have read about it, but according to my situation(need to get /on a client side/ and parse JSON-file) can I use it?

Comment: XHR uses the HTML protocol for its transfer. So you would have to support HTTP on your server :)

Comment: `XHR uses the HTML` - you, probably meant  `HTTP`
Ok, thanks a lot! I wish I could voteUp your answer:)