# Java Socket Server with JavaScript Client

Tags: javascript, java

I put together a Java socket server and client that can send messages to each other, I want to use JavaScript as a client, but... Here is what happens when I'm hosting the Java server and load the JavaScript client.

JavaScript:

```
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:9005');
connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping');
};
```

This Prints in the chrome console:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9005/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line
>   
> WebSocket Error [object Event]

What I'm trying to do is send "Ping" to the Java server, but instead it sends all this stuff than disconnects...

This prints in the Java server console:

> Bread Server running...
>   
> New Connection From: 127.0.0.1:51948
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: GET / HTTP/1.1
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Host: 127.0.0.1:9005
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Connection: Upgrade
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Pragma: no-cache
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Cache-Control: no-cache
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Upgrade: websocket
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Origin: http://markstuff.net
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) 
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Sec-WebSocket-Key: D4Epyc7LwvPdfeDWG0sY2g==
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
>   
> 127.0.0.1:51948: 
>   
> ERROR: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

JavaScript Client:
markstuff.net/socket/ - markstuff.net/socket/client.js
Java Server:
pastebin com cdZjUWQp
Java Client:
pastebin com efEeezcR

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to connect a Websocket client to a bare socket listener in server side. notice that Websocket is not equal to socket. Websocket is a protocol on top of a tcp connection (like how http is on top of tcp) .
so you should either change your server implementation to a Websocket (you can find many java Websocket libraries in internet) or change your client to a socket.
 I'm not sure how to create a socket connection in JS but this topic maybe helpful for this problem: [Connecting to TCP Socket from browser using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407778/connecting-to-tcp-socket-from-browser-using-javascript)

Comment: Thank You! For anyone wondering, I got the WebServer working with this https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/ChatServer.java