# Direct print from iPad using bluetooth

Tags: ios, html, ipad, printing

I use an HTML5 app in fullscreen mode on my iPad and I would like to print the content on a bluetooth printer.
Is there any way how to do it? The idea is, that I would just press a button and the content would be printed without any dialog window.
I know there is AirPrint and so on, but I do not need to print A4 sheets, but receipts on some termotransfer printer. I would be very glad if u could recommend me some printer as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your app running as a browser app? Or are you using a JavaScript/HTML framework to create an app store native app? I don't believe that there is any way you can do this if you aren't running a native app

Comment: It is running as a browser app. :-/

Comment: There is no access to the Core Bluetooth libraries.  You can invoke AirPrint via the standard JavaScript print functions, but this will just print what is in the web view and will display a dialog. You could use an app URL to launch a printing helper app that then returned to your web app, it could be unreliable

Comment: Print via wifi is the same, I suppose...

Comment: Yes, I thought of that and I was just checking. Html5 access to TCP sockets has been defined,  but I am not sure about support on mobile safari - http://www.w3.org/TR/tcp-udp-sockets/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407778/connecting-to-tcp-socket-from-browser-using-javascript