# TCP Message Via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, tcp

I'm trying to send TCP messages (based on user inputs in a web browser) to a standard TCP listening service on a server. i'm not sure how to do this in Ajax for the user in the browser.

Comment: AJAX is really about web requests.  Maybe you want to create a web socket?

Comment: Do you know if the server side code is different if the client is using 'web socket'? for standard TCP i'm running .py file to accept TCP connections. do you know if i can still do this with 'web socket'?

Comment: I don't think it's possible if you can't modify the listener.   Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407778/connecting-to-tcp-socket-from-browser-using-javascript