# Hit tcp server with browser GET request

Tags: node.js, http, tcp

Say I have a tcp server using node.js  net package:

```
 const s = net.createServer(conn => {});

 s.listen(6969, '0.0.0.0', () => {

 });
```

is there a way to hit the server using an HTTP GET request somehow? Perhaps there is a way for an http server to use the same port in the same process?

Comment: maybe you will find this useful : https://superuser.com/questions/907220/if-http-runs-on-a-port-does-that-mean-tcp-can-also-run-on-that-port

Comment: yep this is also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407778/connecting-to-tcp-socket-from-browser-using-javascript

Comment: I don't understand, isn't this just a plain `GET http://<server_ip>:6969` request?

Comment: @shaochuancs this is tcp not http

Answer (score 1):

For HTTP connections use telnet to connect to the port - and send the HTTP commands

https://superuser.com/questions/933346/how-does-one-browse-a-website-using-telnet

For HTTPS connections use openssl s_client

https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-testing-with-openssl.html

Comment: sure, but with a browser is there some magic trick to do this? Some way to make a tcp request with the browser?

Comment: for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407778/connecting-to-tcp-socket-from-browser-using-javascript