# Communicate with a web extension running on a computer on a local network

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

If there is PC (Linux) on the local network, and a web browser (FireFox, Chrome, etc) is running on the PC, and an extension (that I wrote) is installed on the browser, and on another computer on the same network, I want to send messages to the extension and get results back from the extension, how can I achieve this?

All the PC's are mine, and the extension that I am going to write will be used only by me, so I can use any permissions or set up the PC in however way needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a server for this and make all extensions send and receive messages to and from that server...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what languages your extension is written in, but one way would be to send HTTP requests, and listen for them, on special ports. JavaScript has some great options for this:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/

Example app: https://github.com/tommut/HttpRequester

Making TCP listeners in Chrome extensions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337074/3856731